# Rails 4: uniqueness validation not working when object is created through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, unique

let's say I have two models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :question
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :answers
  validates :text, presence: true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question, :inverse_of => :answers

  validates :text, :question, presence: true
  validates :text, uniqueness: true
end
```

Now, if I do:

```
q = Question.new(text: "Test question")
q.answers << Answer.new(text: "non unique text")
q.answers << Answer.new(text: "non unique text")
q.valid?
```

It returns true! And if I try

```
q.save
```

it suceeds! However, if one of the answers had blank text, the presence validation makes q invalid as expected. Besides:

```
a = q.answers.first
a.save
```

Will fail with the expected error of text already taken.

Why the uniqueness validation is not working when the answers are created with the question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The validation will only run when you save an `Answer`. You are only instantiating an instance with `new`, not saving it.

Comment: I stated that the saving was succeeding. I edited the answer to improve clarity about that. Thanks!